# SAS insert column for dynamically determined levels

Tags: sas

I am attempting to set up SAS to do something I am able to easily do in Excel, but am unable to find a way to do effectively. Given the first two tables shown here (dubbed TREE and LEVEL, respectively), I am trying to end up with the third table (FINAL_TREE).

Adding in the *Level* column to TREE, so that it becomes FINAL_TREE works as follows: any given tree must have a number *Apple* which is greater than or equal to *Apple_Req* for a given *Level*, as well as *Orange* greater than or equal to *Orange_Req*. So a *Tree* is given a *Level* to which it meets all given requirements.

So in the example tables, *Tree3* is given *Level1*, despite the fact that it would easily be *Level3* if not for its low *Orange* count.

[image: TREE]

[image: LEVEL]

[image: FINAL_TREE]

In Excel, this can be done using INDEX and finding the MIN of two MATCH functions, but I don't think that can be directly translated into SAS. I imagine there is a way to set this up using explicilty defined nested IF statements, but I am hoping there is a solution which can handle a LEVEL table with any number of levels (so long as the requirements are set up correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, this is quite a bit easier in SAS - in part because there are a *lot* of different ways to do this.

The most straightforward is probably using SQL, if you're familiar with it.  The most similar to what you're doing in Excel, though, is Format, and perhaps the fastest as well.

```
proc format;
  value appleF
    1-<4 = '1'
    5-<15 = '2'
    15-high='3'
  other='0';
 value orangeF
    5-<15  = '1'
    16-<30 = '2'
    30-high= '3'
  other='0';
quit;
```

Now, you can convert the values using `put` and then use `min` just like you would in Excel.  Basically this replaces your `index`.

```
data want;
  set have;
  level = min(put(apple,applef1.),put(orange,orangef1.));
run;
```

You can also produce a format from a dataset directly - see [this paper](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/068-2007.pdf) for example for using `CNTLIN` option on `PROC FORMAT`.